# Show progressBar until UITableView load all Cell

Tags: swift, uitableview

I m building an app using Swift 5.
I create a view with UITableView. I need to display progress bar until all Cell is load. The problem is that for every cell I load an image from url and I need to display progress bar until all images are loaded. This is the code:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftyJSON

class MenuSelectedVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UpdateCartProtocol {

    @IBOutlet weak var lblChiusura: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblStoreAddress: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblStoreName: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableViewData: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var viewBtnRating: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var viewProductCart: UIView!
    var store:StoreResponseModel!
    var category:ProductCategory!
    var products:[Product] = []
    var quantity:Int!
    var price:Float!
    var cart:ResponseCartModel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblNumProduct: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblTotalChart: UILabel!
    //MARK:- ViewDidLoad
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.showProgressBar()
        tableViewData.delegate = self
        tableViewData.dataSource = self
        self.settingUi()
        getCart()
        getProductByCategory()
        self.hideProgressBar()
    }
    
    func getProductByCategory(){
        self.showProgressBar()
        var paramDict : [String:AnyObject] = [:]
        paramDict["store_id"]  = store.id as AnyObject
        paramDict["category_id"]  = category.id as AnyObject
        paramDict["activate"]  = "1" as AnyObject
        CommunicationManeger.callPostServiceReturnJson(apiUrl: RouterProd.get_product_by_store.url(), parameters: paramDict,  parentViewController: self, successBlock: { (responseData, message) in

            DispatchQueue.main.async { [self] in
                do {
                    let products = try JSONDecoder().decode(ResponseProductModel.self, from: responseData as! Data)
                    if(products.status == "1") {
                        self.products = products.result
                        self.tableViewData.reloadData()
                    } else {
                        self.products = []
                        //self.table_List.reloadData()
                        Utility.noDataFound(products.message, tableViewOt: self.tableViewData, parentViewController: self)
                    }
                }catch{
                   print("errore durante la decodifica dei dati: \(error)")
                   Utility.noDataFound("Errore", tableViewOt: self.tableViewData, parentViewController: self)
               }
                
                self.hideProgressBar()
            }
        }, failureBlock: { (error : Error) in
            Utility.showAlertMessage(withTitle: EMPTY_STRING, message: (error.localizedDescription), delegate: nil,parentViewController: self)
            self.hideProgressBar()
        })
    }
    
    func updateCartFromProtocol(prodottoAggiornato: ResultCartModel) {
        self.price = nil
        self.quantity = nil
        //devo aggiornare il prodotto appena modificato
        //verifico questo prodotto a che numero riga era
        let position:Int = try! searchProductPosition(nomeProdotto: prodottoAggiornato.productDetails.productName) as! Int
        if(position != nil){
            //dal array recupero l oggetto inq uesta posizione
            self.cart.result.indices.filter { self.cart.result[$0].productDetails.productName == prodottoAggiornato.productDetails.productName}
                .forEach { self.cart.result[$0].quantity = prodottoAggiornato.quantity }
            let indexPosition = IndexPath(row: position, section: 0)
            tableViewData.reloadRows(at: [indexPosition], with: .none)
        }
        getCart()
    }
    
    func getCart(){
        self.showProgressBar()
        var paramDict : [String:AnyObject] = [:]
        paramDict["user_id"]  = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: USERID) as AnyObject?
        CommunicationManeger.callPostServiceReturnJson(apiUrl: RouterProd.get_cart.url(), parameters: paramDict,  parentViewController: self, successBlock: { (responseData, message) in

            DispatchQueue.main.async { [self] in
                do {
                    self.cart = try JSONDecoder().decode(ResponseCartModel.self, from: responseData as! Data)
                    if(cart.status == "1") {
                        for product in cart.result {
                            if(product.type == TYPE_PRODUCT){
                                let detail = product.productDetails
                                self.updateQuantity(quantita: Int(product.quantity)!)
                                //se ci sono aggiunte il prezzo va
                                //preso dal prodotto generale altrimenti
                                //dal suo dettaglio
                                if(product.ingredientPrice.isEmpty){
                                    self.updateTotalPrice(quantita: Int(product.quantity)!, prezzo: Float(detail.price)!)
                                }else{
                                    self.updateTotalPrice(quantita: Int(product.quantity)!, prezzo: Float(product.ingredientPrice)!)
                                }
                                
                            }
                        }
                        
                    } else {
                        
                    }
                }catch{
                   print("errore durante la decodifica dei dati: \(error)")
                   
               }
                
                self.hideProgressBar()
            }
        }, failureBlock: { (error : Error) in
            Utility.showAlertMessage(withTitle: EMPTY_STRING, message: (error.localizedDescription), delegate: nil,parentViewController: self)
            self.hideProgressBar()
        })
    }
    
    func settingUi(){
        self.viewBtnRating.setCornerRadius(cornerRadius: 14, borderColor: nil, borderWidth: nil)
        viewProductCart.setCornerRadius(cornerRadius: 25, borderColor: nil, borderWidth: nil)
        self.lblStoreName.text = self.store.firstName
        self.lblStoreAddress.text = self.store.address
    }
    
    @IBAction func btnBack(_ sender: Any) {
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }

    @IBAction func btnViewCart(_ sender: Any) {
        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AddToCartVC") as! AddToCartVC
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
    
    //MARK:- TableView Methods
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
        
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.products.count
        
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            if let lastVisibleIndexPath = tableViewData.indexPathsForVisibleRows?.last {
                    if indexPath == lastVisibleIndexPath {
                        print("finisco di scrivere le righe")
                    }
            }
        }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableViewData.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MenuSelectedCell") as! MenuSelectedCell
        let obj = self.products[indexPath.row]
        let image = obj.image[0].image
        let url = URL(string: image)!
        if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
            cell.imgFood.image = UIImage(data: data)
        }
        cell.lblNameProduct.text = obj.productName
        cell.lblDescriptionProduct.text = obj.resultDescription
        cell.lblPriceProduct.text = obj.price + " €"
        //devo verificare se i prodotti della categoria sono stati già selezionati oppure no.
        do{
            let cartObj = try? searchProduct(nomeProdotto: obj.productName)
            if(cartObj != nil){
                cell.lblQuantity.text = cartObj?.quantity
                cell.quantita = Int(cartObj!.quantity)
            }else{
                cell.lblQuantity.text = "0"
                cell.quantita = 0
            }
        }catch{
            
        }
        cell.buttonAdd.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.buttonAdd.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addQuantity(button:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        cell.buttonMinus.addTarget(self, action: #selector(removeQuantity(button:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        return cell
    }
    
    func searchProduct(nomeProdotto: String) -> ResultCartModel?{
        if(self.cart != nil){
            if let i = self.cart.result.firstIndex(where: { $0.productDetails.productName == nomeProdotto }) {
                return self.cart.result[i]
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
    
    func searchProductPosition(nomeProdotto: String) -> Int?{
        if(self.cart != nil){
            if let i = self.cart.result.firstIndex(where: { $0.productDetails.productName == nomeProdotto }) {
                return i
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
    
    func updateQuantity(quantita: Int){
        do{
            if(quantity == nil){
                quantity = quantita
            }else{
                self.quantity += quantita
            }
            lblNumProduct.text = String(self.quantity) + " Prodotti"
        }catch{
            print("caught: \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    func updateTotalPrice(quantita: Int, prezzo: Float){
        do{
            if(self.price == nil){
                self.price = Float(quantita) * prezzo
            }else{
                self.price += Float(quantita) * prezzo
            }
            lblTotalChart.text = "€ " +
                Utility.twoDecimals(number: self.price!)
        }catch{
            print("caught: \(error)")
        }
    }

    

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The system does not load all the cells in a `UITableView` at once. Instead it loads only as many cells as are visible, and displays those.  When a user begins to scroll it may remove some cells that are no longer visible, and will add other cells for the newly-visible content.

You don't want try to load the graphics for your catalog items when you are creating the cell.

Instead move the data loading into your model class and load the images there.  You could put a placeholder cell in the table to show that the catalog images are loading in the background then populate the table once that loading is complete.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but could you explain me bettere with some example code?